# Can I recover a lost domain if I prove I can send emails from that domain’s email addresses?

Tags: domain-registration, expired-domains

Last year I didn’t renew my domain by mistake. And it was taken by someone else.

The nameservers were never changed, so I could still use my GSuite registered with this domain for one year (for “free”).

Now, the domain just expired and has gone into ClientHold status (even though the expiry date shows an extra year) so it is no longer resolving, but I can still send emails from it.

Is there anything I can do to get it back asap?
It does not seem to be used at all (as I said, nameservers never changed for one year) and I would certainly make use of it. 
Does it help if I can prove I have the outgoing emails? (i.e. I can send emails from all accounts in this domain)

Comment: Anyone can send an email using another domain (see "email spoofing"), _receiving_ email is another matter... I'd suggest using a reputable domain backorder service, and checking if it appears in domain auction lists, which can circumvent deletion and pending backorders.

Comment: Oh, well I could also prove regular use of several email accounts on that domain, but I guess it’s of no use. Which would be these reputable services? Can they get a domain even if it’s currently in grace/redemption (clientHold) status?